# Laravel 5 multilanguage url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

How to develop multi language url in laravel 5.

like

```
abc.com/en/product/123

     abc.com/de/profile/234
```

This is my  route.php and i have created two folder inside lang folder en and de. Inside those i have created same file with same array with different value.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{locale}'),  function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
          return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::any('user/{id}', function ($locale,$id) {
          return 'User '.$id;
    });

     Route::get('signup', 'SignupController@index');
     Route::post('signup', 'SignupController@create');
});
```

Comment: @slick is right. You simply allow the user to choose a specific language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just create a route for switching language and nothing else. Once the language is switched, url will be always the same (so without `en` or `pl` or whatever):

`abc.com/product/123`

Which language is currently being used should be kept in Laravel session variable.

Comment: I copy/paste the link to a cool product to a friend. How would my friend view the page in the language I am viewing it? (My imaginary friend does not speak Fallback, the default language of your website.)

Comment: How some websites display your native language while you visit them for the first time and you have never set up language before? I get your point but in this case you can set the language based on user location, agent, ip or what ever.

Comment: Don't do this! If you have only one URL and different content e.g. English and German content this will result in bad search engine results. To fix this problem you can either do it like `abc.com/en/product/123` or something like `abc.com/product/123-en.html`. See this link for more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Comment: @slick, that logic fails for any country with more than one language. Canada has (according to Wikipedia, dated to 2001) ~70% English-only speakers, ~15% French-only speakers.

Comment: Slick i need url should be like abc.com/en/product/123